# Is "whimper" the same as "say with pain"?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> "How is this possible?"
>   whimpered the old man. "I saw you die by the hands of our enemies. I thought you were a goner!"

I am seriously wondering if you can use the verb whimper that way. I am saying that, because it seems to mean

> To cry or sob with soft intermittent sounds; whine
>
> To complain.

Now, I've never seen it used to mean "complain" and I always see it being used as "say with intermittent sobs" or "say with pain", but the first definition doesn't match, because when you cry you don't talk. So is there a simple explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"so-and-so whimpered" is understood to mean that so-and-so was talking and whimpering, but **not necessarily simultaneously.** Hence, the definition is not contradictory.